# Render HTML Table in react native

Tags: react-native

In my project, I've used **react-native-render-html** to render the html. But the table content is not displayed correctly.

```js
import RenderHtml from 'react-native-render-html';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

const html = `
        <html>
        <head></head>
            <body>
            <style>
                table, th, td {
                    border:1px solid black;
                }
            </style>

            <table style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                <td>Emil</td>
                <td>Tobias</td>
                <td>Linus</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>16</td>
                <td>14</td>
                <td>10</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    `;

    const webViewProps = {
        originWhitelist: "*"
    };

    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <RenderHtml
                source={{ html }}
                WebView={WebView}
                defaultWebViewProps={webViewProps}
            />
        </View>
    );
```

[Click to view result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wtgq2.png)

Can someone give me advice on how to solve this problem? I have html table data which is generated by Ckeditor from my website, so I have to find the way to handle.

Comment: Take the time to learn React Native instead of trying to make it work with HTML. Here's a search with several good results https://duckduckgo.com/?q=react+native+table&ia=web

Comment: I have html data which is generated by Ckeditor from my website, so I have to find the way to handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://meliorence.github.io/react-native-render-html/docs/guides/styling

Reading Their guide on styling, I didn't find an example of styling the HTML elements with a `<style>` tag, instead they offer a few props, like `​classesStyles`, `idsStyles` or `​tagsStyles` to target the elements inside the HTML. (also the css should be CSS in JS)

Unfortunately, none of the above props actually worked, the only way I was able to handle it was to pass inline styles.

Comment: I have added style attribute to each <table>, <tr>, <td> tag and CSS attribute has effect on the table. However, if I add the **rowspan** and **colspan** attributes of the <table> tag cannot be used.